# How to compare json items and values of inputs so that if they match, add css properties to inputs parents?

Tags: jquery

$pmsColorData contains JSON, in this example with keys 312 and 313. But the keys and their quantity change.

It is necessary to compare (in `each()` function):

`$pmsColorData[key_number].name`
and
`$(".autocomplete-deluxe-item input").val()`

If `$pmsColorData[key_number].name` in json matches the value of the input, then I need to set the value `$pmsColorData[312].src` for `$(".autocomplete-deluxe-item")` in the background-image css property.

html:

```
<div class="field--name-field-pms-colors" data-additional-color-data="{&quot;312&quot;:{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Black&quot;,&quot;hex&quot;:&quot;#000000&quot;,&quot;src&quot;:&quot;http:\/\/sitename\/sites\/default\/files\/pms_colors\/Black.png&quot;},&quot;313&quot;:{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Metallic Silver&quot;,&quot;hex&quot;:&quot;#D3D4DE&quot;,&quot;src&quot;:&quot;http:\/\/sitename\/sites\/default\/files\/pms_colors\/Metallic%20Silver.png&quot;}}">
  <div class="autocomplete-deluxe-container">
    <span class="autocomplete-deluxe-item">Black
      <a class="autocomplete-deluxe-item-delete" href=""></a>
      <input type="hidden" value="Black"></span>
     <span class="autocomplete-deluxe-item">Metallic Silver
       <a class="autocomplete-deluxe-item-delete" href=""></a>
       <input type="hidden" value="Metallic Silver">
     </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    makeColorCircle();
});

function makeColorCircle() {
  const $fieldPmsColor = $(".field--name-field-pms-colors");
  const $pmsColorData = $fieldPmsColor.data("additional-color-data");
  console.log($pmsColorData);
}
```

`console.log($pmsColorData);` show:

```
{
    "312": {
        "name": "Black",
        "hex": "#000000",
        "src": "http://sitename/sites/default/files/pms_colors/Black.png"
    },
    "313": {
        "name": "Metallic Silver",
        "hex": "#D3D4DE",
        "src": "http://sitename/sites/default/files/pms_colors/Metallic%20Silver.png"
    }
}
```

How to implement it?

Sandbox:
https://jsfiddle.net/gikooo/j37od8cL/6/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this sould work:

```js
function makeColorCircle() {

    const fieldPmsColor = $(".field--name-field-pms-colors");
    const pmsColorData = fieldPmsColor.data("additional-color-data");

    const elements = $(fieldPmsColor).find(".autocomplete-deluxe-container span.autocomplete-deluxe-item");

    elements.each(function (i, span) {

        const searchedName = $(span).find("input").val();

        for (let key in pmsColorData) {

            if (pmsColorData[key].name === searchedName) {

                $(span).css("background-image", `url('${pmsColorData[key].src}')`);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

If the json data had been an array of objects instead of nested objects, it would have been possible to avoid the *for* loop and use the Array.prototype.find() method to search for the desired row.